# How to create XML file to some folder?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8

How to create XML file to some folder?

```
isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("**Folder/XmlFile.xml**", FileMode.Create, isoStore);
```

Comment: I could create xml file without folder. But i don't know how to add folder directory.

Answer (score 2):

Snatched directly from the [Quickstart: Working with files and folders in Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681698%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Check out the section "Creating a folder and writing to a text file"

```
private async void btnWrite_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await WriteToFile();

    // Update UI.
    this.btnWrite.IsEnabled = false;
    this.btnRead.IsEnabled = true;
}

private async Task WriteToFile()
{
    // Get the text data from the textbox. 
    byte[] fileBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(this.textBox1.Text.ToCharArray());

    // Get the local folder.
    StorageFolder local = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

    // Create a new folder name DataFolder.
    var dataFolder = await local.CreateFolderAsync("DataFolder",
    CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

    // Create a new file named DataFile.txt.
    var file = await dataFolder.CreateFileAsync("DataFile.txt",
    CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

    // Write the data from the textbox.
    using (var s = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
    {
        s.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below function will save the Jagged array double[][] to the XML. You may use it by modify to your own data type:

```
   private void Save(double[][] m, string filePath)
    {
        //Open a file stream 
        System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(filePath, System.IO.FileMode.Create);
        // Create a xml Serializer object
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer xmlSer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(double[][]));

        xmlSer.Serialize(fs, m);
        // Close the file stream
        fs.Close();         
    }
```

Just instead of the `double [][] m` you should put your own type.